# Default Unix test page raplacement

Tags: unix, centos

I hast my site on Unix, using CentOS. Is there a way to modify the default CentOS screen? Where is the file stored?

Comment: Do you know what web server you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed Apache then you'll probably find the file in `/var/www/html` (according to what I can find with Google).  You'll also find all the configuration files for Apache in /etc/httpd.

You may also find [this CentOS documentation](http://centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-httpd.html) useful.